# Unable to validate SHA 256 Xml Signature using Java

Tags: java, xml, rsa-sha256

I Have one xml which is signed by following signinfo

**XML**

```
<SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
         <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>XYZ</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
```

I would like to verify my signature which is coming from trusted source.
I have signature value and Keyinfo with me.

For Example :

```
<SignatureValue>XYZ</SignatureValue>
      <KeyInfo>
         <KeyValue>
            <RSAKeyValue>
               <Modulus>ABC</Modulus>
               <Exponent>XYX</Exponent>
            </RSAKeyValue>
         </KeyValue>
      </KeyInfo>
```

All in All my Signature tag looks like this

**XML**

```
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <SignedInfo>
         <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
         <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
         <Reference URI="">
            <Transforms>
               <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
            </Transforms>
            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <DigestValue>XYZ</DigestValue>
         </Reference>
      </SignedInfo>
      <SignatureValue>XYZ</SignatureValue>
          <KeyInfo>
             <KeyValue>
                <RSAKeyValue>
                   <Modulus>ABC</Modulus>
                   <Exponent>XYX</Exponent>
                </RSAKeyValue>
             </KeyValue>
          </KeyInfo>
   </Signature>
```

To Verify Signature I used a lot of methods but I could not verify Signature with SHA256 Algo.

**Java**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyException;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.crypto.AlgorithmMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.KeySelector;
import javax.xml.crypto.KeySelectorException;
import javax.xml.crypto.KeySelectorResult;
import javax.xml.crypto.XMLCryptoContext;
import javax.xml.crypto.XMLStructure;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.Reference;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.SignatureMethod;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignatureFactory;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.dom.DOMValidateContext;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyInfo;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.KeyValue;
import javax.xml.crypto.dsig.keyinfo.X509Data;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

/**
 * This is a simple example of validating an XML Signature using the JSR 105
 * API. It assumes the key needed to validate the signature is contained in a
 * KeyValue KeyInfo.
 */
public class Validate {

    //
    // Synopsis: java Validate [document]
    //
    // where "document" is the name of a file containing the XML document
    // to be validated.
    //
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String fileName = "signedXMl.xml";

        // Instantiate the document to be validated 
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
        Document doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
                new FileInputStream(fileName));

        // Find Signature element
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS,
                "Signature");
        if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
            throw new Exception("Cannot find Signature element");
        }

        // Create a DOM XMLSignatureFactory that will be used to unmarshal the
        // document containing the XMLSignature
        XMLSignatureFactory fac = XMLSignatureFactory.getInstance("DOM");

        // Create a DOMValidateContext and specify a KeyValue KeySelector
        // and document context
        DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext(
                new KeyValueKeySelector(), nl.item(0));

        // unmarshal the XMLSignature
        XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);

        // Validate the XMLSignature (generated above)
        boolean coreValidity = signature.validate(valContext);

        // Check core validation status
        if (coreValidity == false) {
            System.err.println("Signature failed core validation");
            boolean sv = signature.getSignatureValue().validate(valContext);
            System.out.println("signature validation status: " + sv);
            // check the validation status of each Reference
            Iterator<?> i = signature.getSignedInfo().getReferences().iterator();
            for (int j = 0; i.hasNext(); j++) {
                boolean refValid = ((Reference) i.next()).validate(valContext);
                System.out.println("ref[" + j + "] validity status: "
                        + refValid);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Signature passed core validation");
        }
    }

    /**
     * KeySelector which retrieves the public key out of the KeyValue element
     * and returns it. NOTE: If the key algorithm doesn't match signature
     * algorithm, then the public key will be ignored.
     */
    private static class KeyValueKeySelector extends KeySelector {
        public KeySelectorResult select(KeyInfo keyInfo,
                KeySelector.Purpose purpose, AlgorithmMethod method,
                XMLCryptoContext context) throws KeySelectorException {

            if (keyInfo == null) {
                throw new KeySelectorException("Null KeyInfo object!");
            }
            SignatureMethod sm = (SignatureMethod) method;
            List<?> list = keyInfo.getContent();

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                XMLStructure xmlStructure = (XMLStructure) list.get(i);
                if (xmlStructure instanceof X509Data) {
                    PublicKey pk = null;
                    List<?> l = ((X509Data) xmlStructure).getContent();
                    if (l.size() > 0) {
                        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) l.get(0);
                        pk = cert.getPublicKey();
                        if (algEquals(sm.getAlgorithm(), pk.getAlgorithm())) {
                            return new SimpleKeySelectorResult(pk);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (xmlStructure instanceof KeyValue) {
                    PublicKey pk = null;
                    try {
                        pk = ((KeyValue) xmlStructure).getPublicKey();
                    } catch (KeyException ke) {
                        throw new KeySelectorException(ke);
                    }
                    // make sure algorithm is compatible with method
                    if (algEquals(sm.getAlgorithm(), pk.getAlgorithm())) {
                        return new SimpleKeySelectorResult(pk);
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new KeySelectorException("No KeyValue element found!");
        }

        // @@@FIXME: this should also work for key types other than DSA/RSA
        static boolean algEquals(String algURI, String algName) {
            if (algName.equalsIgnoreCase("DSA") && algURI.equalsIgnoreCase(SignatureMethod.DSA_SHA1)) {
                return true;
            } else if (algName.equalsIgnoreCase("RSA")
                    && algURI.equalsIgnoreCase("http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256")) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    private static class SimpleKeySelectorResult implements KeySelectorResult {
        private PublicKey pk;

        SimpleKeySelectorResult(PublicKey pk) {
            this.pk = pk;
        }

        public Key getKey() {
            return pk;
        }
    }
}
```